# Vote to choose accepted answer.

Tags: feature-request

The community bot brings up a lot of questions that have been answered except the original asker never accepted. This causes a lot of old questions to be put into the unanswered pile and on the homepage. I think we need a privilege to vote for an accepted answer on a question older than a certain date 30 days for example. It will help us get to the "truly" unanswered questions faster.

example 
1. [Installed PHP module and restarted nginx but but PHP configuration isn't updating?](https://serverfault.com/questions/168302/installed-php-module-and-restarted-nginx-but-but-php-configuration-isnt-updating)
2. [Setting max_allowed_packet for mysql on solaris 10](https://serverfault.com/questions/36890/setting-max-allowed-packet-for-mysql-on-solaris-10)

Comment: This has been proposed over on the "master" meta-site: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/community-vote-for-accepted-answer-rep-5000-only - I am going to close this question to direct people to that question as it will receive more publicity. Feel free to voice your opinion there!

Comment: this has been brought up many times already; I suspect we'll see it eventually. It's just not there yet.